# Java Tuple Without Creating Multiple Type Parameters

Tags: java, tuples

Is there any way to create a [`Tuple`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) in Java, without having to create multiple classes?

For example, it is possible to make a different class for every different type of Tuple, each with a different number of [`Type Parameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
public class SingleTuple<T>{}
public class DoubleTuple<T1, T2>{}
public class TripleTuple<T1, T2, T3>{}
public class QuadraTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>{}
public class PentaTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>{}
```

And it's also possible to create a Tuple object without any [`Type Parameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) by just doing this:

```
public class Tuple{

    private Object[] objects;

    public Tuple(Object... objects){
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public Object get(int index){
        return this.objects[index];
    }
}
```

Except if this is used, all of the objects would have to be casted to their correct subclass once they are taken out of the Tuple, making it like an `ArrayList<Object>`, but with less features.

Is there any way to just create one singular class, and have multiple [`Type Parameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) without defining all of them (like in the first example), using something like this?

```
public class Tuple<T...>{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. If you want type safety, you'll have to create them like you've presented in your first code snippet. There are libraries that do this for you, [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/tuple), for example.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a hideous workaround.

All you need is a class `Pair<A, B>`. Then, instead of a `QuadraTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>` you could have a `Pair<T1, Pair<T2, Pair<T3, T4>>>`.

To get the `T3` out of it, you'd have to write `T3 t3 = quadraTuple.second().second().first();`. It's type-safe and extends to any number of parameters.

Never do this.

Answer (score -2):

I designed a library in Java that implements a type-unsafe tuple (`Tuple` class), inspired to the tuples of the Python language.
As in other answers, if you want type-safeness in Java, you should define a generic type for each element of the tuple. Alternatively, you can check the expected type at runtime, and you can catch a kind of Java Exception. My library also exposes a typed tuple (`BoundTuple` class) that allows to perform more strict type checking at runtime, in order to minimize programming errors, where necessary. To perform strict type checking, the developer must create a schema (`TupleSchema` class) and he must specify the expected type when invoking the `get()` method on a bound tuple instance.

I invite you to see my repository on GitHub: [JTuple](https://github.com/sv-giampa/JTuple/tree/master/JTuple/src/jtuple)

This tuple implementation is very useful for me and I am continuously adopting it in many other projects.